# Proof of odd number of divisors of a perfect square

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

How do we prove that a perfect square has an odd number of divisors?
Eg 1024 is a perfect square and it has $11$ divisors comprising of

$2^0$,$2^1$,$2^2$,...$2^10$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $1, \sqrt n$ , and $n$ all divide $n$. So that's three divisors. Then any other divisor less than $\sqrt n$ must be accompanied by another divisor that is *more than* $\sqrt n$ (why??).